# Corcel/Laravel generate Multi-Levels Menu (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I am trying to get a multi-level menu with Corcel within WordPress. I have read the documentation about it, but do not exactly understand how to manage this.

The documentation tells me group the items within the `$menu->items` collection by their parent ID. But how?

The documentation part can be found here: https://github.com/corcel/corcel#multi-levels-menus

What i tried so far: ( I only get a "Call to a member function offsetSet() on null")

```
$menu   = Menu::location( 'main' )->first();
$items  = Menu::location( 'main' )->first()->items;
$parent = $items->first()->parent();
$menu->items->groupBy( $parent->ID );

foreach ( $menu->items as $item ) {
    $title = $item->instance()->title;
}
```

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Did u installed it through Composer?

Comment: yes. it is part of the development environment and installed via composer

Comment: well I also got into this and managed to solve it this way:
`$items = $menu->items->groupBy(function ($item) {
 return $item->meta->_menu_item_menu_item_parent;
});`